# Specific url for controller using @PathVariable in RequestMapping issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, url-routing

I am facing some difficulties when trying to create a certain url for @RequestMapping in a spring controller. 
First of all, because of the framework the project uses, there is a controller method mapped to the following url: "**/{pageLabelOrId}**"

Second, I have another controller method mapped to "**/{pageName}.html**". This works fine, meaning that if I try to access from browser "**www.applicationUrl/something.html**" this url if captured by the second method as is intended.

Now here is my problem. I must handle a somehow different but also similar url in a distinct method as follows: "**/something-{parameter1}_{parameter2}_{parameter3}**"
Trying to access "**www.applicationUrl/something-1_2_3**" will trigger the first controller: "**/{pageLabelOrId}**" instead of the desired one.

Handling this kind of url("**/something-1_2_3**") is a requirement and I cannot change it to something like "**/something/{param1}/{param2}/{param3}**" which I am sure it will work.

I have observed however, that writing a controller method mapped to "**/something-{param}**" will work and will capture my three parameters in one PathVariable(like "1_2_3") that I can parse afterwards by "_".

Does anyone have any idea of why does spring has this behavior and if I can somehow make it to work using three different path variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring 3.1+ uses a `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` to create `RequestMappingInfo` objects which map your controller handler methods to their corresponding `@RequestMapping` paths. When the `DispatcherServlet` receives a request, it uses the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` again to determine which handler method should be used.

The way it is currently implemented, it finds all the registered `RequestMappingInfo` objects that match the request and then sorts them based on a number of rules, basically those defined in `AntPathMatcher` and `AntPatternComparator`.

You'll have to configure your `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` bean to use a custom `PathMatcher` with your own rules for comparing.

How you do this depends on how you are doing your configuration. If you use a `@Configuration` class, you can do

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    ...

    @Override
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        RequestMappingHandlerMapping mapping = super.requestMappingHandlerMapping();
        mapping.setPathMatcher(pathMatcher()); // some PathMatcher bean
        return mapping;
    }

    ...
}
```

The `RequestMappingInfo` objects created by this `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` will internally use this `PathMatcher`. They will be sorted based on its `Comparator`.